# Missed the time of the day, hour, minute on every profile?

Tags: discussion, design, closed-questions, user-profile-page, vote-to-reopen

I've noticed, and I hope that I'm not wrong, that every user profile is missing **the time** and **the date** when they last logged in TeX.SE.

The question, although synthetic, refers to the *opening* or *closing* of questions.

*I generally wait 12 or at most 24 hours from the last connection of the user.*

Comment: That's been announced on main meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive . This has nothing to do with tex.se, but is network wide.